# Extracting variable data from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object of the form

```
var fruits = {
    "1": {
         "id": 1,
         "description": "Apple",
         "groupID": 0
    },
    "2": {
         "id": 2,
         "description": "Peach",
         "groupID": 0
     }
}
```

This javascript has been obtained as a JSON response after AJAX call. How do I extract the variable data (description) here?
P.S. no jQuery

what I did was

```
 for(i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
     j=i+1;
     console.log(fruits[j].description);
 }
```

it says fruits[j] is undefined.

Comment: Did you take a look at [Javascript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) before asking ?

Comment: @Zenoo please don't link to that awful site. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Zenoo yes I did. Let me repeat once again that this is an object that I am getting after AJAX call. console.log(fruits); prints well but when I do console.log(fruits[1].description); it returns undefined.

Comment: You have not put the actual code, nor the output that you are seeing in the question.  It could be as simple as failing to use `JSON.parse()` on the response from the Ajax call.  You need to provide what you actually have, not attempt to paraphrase it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for ... in` loop to loop trough them and get the descriptions, or `Object.values` and `map` to get an array of the values;

```js
 var fruits =
  {
    "1": {
          "id": 1,
          "description": "Apple",
          "groupID": 0
         },
    "2": {
          "id": 2,
          "description": "Peach",
          "groupID": 0
         }
  }
  
for(let key in fruits)
{
  console.log(fruits[key].description);
}

console.log(Object.values(fruits).map(v => v.description));
```

Comment: I am getting this object after an AJAX call. When I do console.log(fruits); , it print well, but if I try to access any of its members as you said, it says undefined. What do I do?

Comment: @user5673235 If `Object.values(fruits)` does not return anything meaningful, then it's not an object...

Comment: console.log(Object.values(fruits)) ? says "Unresolved function or method values()"